# Bundle names of built plugins

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pde, pde

Once the plugins are built the bundle name contains the time stamp, for e.g. 
    org.apache.batik.transcoder.source_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar

Also in manifest.mf the Bundle Version contains the same time stamp.

I want to keep the timestamp in manifest.mf but remove in bundle file name. Is that possible?

Comment: How do you build your plug-ins?

Comment: I have ant scripts written, which builds the features via PDE Build. All this configured via Bamboo build tool.

Comment: In this case, you must add a new task to rename the plug-ins. To my knowledge, PDEBuild does not allow you to customize the resulting name...

Comment: Yes, I also found that PDE Build does not allow such functionality. I wrote a custom task using Groovy, which works fine. Anyway thanks for the clarifications...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, PDEBuild does not allow you to customize the resulting name...

You might want to consider using [Tycho](http://eclipse.org/tycho/) for your build as this is the [tool of choice](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CBI) for Eclipse these days.